# show contextmenu on specfic node of jstree based on some condition

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jstree

```js
 $scope.contextMenu = {
  

  "Export" : {
   "label" : "Export",
   "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt",
   "_class" : "contextMenuListClass",
   "action" : function(obj, data) {
    console.log(obj);

   }
  },
 
 };
```

```html
<div class="tree-div" id='myTree' style="display: none;">

 <js-tree tree-plugins="contextmenu,wholerow,sort,search,types"
  tree-types="types" tree-contextmenu="contextMenu" tree-data="scope"
  tree-model="data" selected
  tree-events="dblclick:onTreeNodeDoubleClick"></js-tree>
</div>
```

I'm using angular jsTree-directive.My requirement is to show context menu on specific node of Jstree first I check the condition on selected node if selected node meet that condition then context menu will appear on that node or else context menu will not visible for that node.

Comment: so you want the style `display none` to work for the parent div on a condition right?

Comment: i don't get it.my requirement is like that   1). get the selectedNode 2). if selected node meet the condition then show the context menu.

Comment: its something like that if (r.data.level === "level2") {
     //show context menu 
    }